# Assigning data layers to grid in Repast J

Tags: java, grid, agent-based-modeling, repast-simphony

I am trying to write an ABM in Repast Java Suite and am using a 3D grid for that. Two questions about the grid:
1) I want to assign a functional value for each (x,y) combination in the grid- E.g. for each f(x,y)=x+y. So, when an agent is at point (x,y), it will know that corresponding z value is z=f(x,y)=x+y. How can I assign a data layer to the grid to do that?

2) Again for the same grid, agents should be able to know that whether specific patch is visited or not. It will be updated whenever an agent visits that patch.

In general, my problem is to assign additional methods, data etc. to the grid interface. As it's a fundamental question for my simulation, I can't move further without solving it.. Answers really appreciated.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

a) It sounds like you might want a [GridValueLayer](http://repast.sourceforge.net/docs/api/repast_simphony/repast/simphony/valueLayer/GridValueLayer.html) on a 2D grid, rather than a 3D grid.  You use a 3D grid if you want the agents to be able to move in a 3 dimensional space, but a 2D grid if they move in 2D space, even if you want them to then read a value for each location.

A GridValueLayer can be used on an n-dimensional grid and holds a value for each cell (location specified by n int values).  For your example, you might want the GridValueLayer to hold the value x+y for each cell in the 2D grid.

e.g.

```
int[] dimensions = new int[]{xMax, yMax};
AbstractGrid  myBasicGrid = new AbstractGrid("exampleGrid", new SimpleGridAdder(), new WrapAroundBorders(), new SingleOccupancyCellAccessor(), dimensions);
GridValueLayer mySimpleGridValueLayer = new GridValueLayer("simpleAddLayer",true,dimensions);

for (int i = 0; i < xMax, i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < yMax, j++)
    {
        int[] coord = new int[]{i,j};
        mySimpleGridValueLayer.set(i+j, coord);
    }
}
```

b) This could be done in a number of ways.  I suggest the GridValueLayer again.  In the agent code, at the point that you do the move to a point in the grid, you set the GridValueLayer for that coordinate to 1.

A final note.  You could implement your own grid.  As long as it conforms to Repast's Grid interface, or you can extend AbstractGrid.  For instance, if you extend AbstractGrid and then have methods getSum(int... coords), which simply returns the sum of the coords array and getVisited(int... coords) to solve your problem.  You could also make it implement the [ProjectionListener](http://repast.sourceforge.net/docs/api/repast_simphony/repast/simphony/space/projection/ProjectionListener.html) interface, listening for a ProjectionEvent of type OBJECT_MOVED and then setting the value of visited to true for that location.